# Sort files in different directories based on file name

Tags: bash, sorting, find

I have several different directories within my working directory, In each of these subdirectories, I have a file that ends in "**.breaks.bed**" that look like this:

```
1       93961   93962   sample_1           1
1       115757  115758  sample_2           5
1       115796  115797  sample_3           68
1       713966  713967  sample_4           7
```

I want to select these files based on this extension above, and then sort them by the 5th column and rank from highest to lowest (without having to create a new output file) like so:

```
1       115796  115797  sample_3           68
1       713966  713967  sample_4           7
1       115757  115758  sample_2           5
1       93961   93962   sample_1           1
```

So far, my inital attempt has been to try and use `find` and then `sort`. I think this is close, but not quite there.

```
find . -name "*.break.bed" -type f sort -o,-k5,5nr "*.break.bed"{,}
```

As always, any help is always appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
find . -name "*.break.bed" -type f -exec sort -k5,5nr -o {} {} \;
```